# Linux sed command does not change the target file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

With my shell script, when I run `./Test1 hello result`.

It is supposed to take `hello` as standard input and result as standard output. The shell should remove any whitespace before `<td>`, `</td>`, and `abc`

So, I write the script this way

```
tr -d [:blank:] < $1
grep -r "<td>" $1 | sed -r 's/<td>//g' > $2
sed -r 's/<\/td>//g' $2
sed -r 's/abc//g' $2
```

However, when I run this command, the content of result file is exactly the same as the content of hello file (the only difference is the whitespace is removed)

The file hello content:

```
<td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
    <td>hello</td>
<td>abc</td>
 <td>abc</td>
```

How do I get `sed` to apply the change to the target file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to store the changes from `sed` back to the file use the `-i` option:

```
$ cat file
<head>abc</head>
    <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
<h1>abc</h1>

$ sed -ni '/<td>/{s/^\s*//;s/abc//;s/<\/\?td>//g;p}' file

$ cat file
hello
hello
hello
```

**Edit:** The regexp is clearer if we use a different separator with `sed` and use the extended regexp option `-r`:

```
$ sed -r 's_</?td>__g' file
    hello
      hello
        hello
    abc
     abc
```

The `?` make the previous character optional so the `/` doesn't have to be present making the regexp match `<td>` and `</td>` in one.

Comment: what is <\/\?td>? is it different from <\/td>?

Comment: additionally, I used grep because hello is an html file, so there's <head> etc, So, I want to find line that contain <td> in the file, delete the <td>, and put it in $2 file. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Also see edit for only matching lines containing `<td>` replacing the need for `grep`.

Comment: so, do you mean I have to remove that <head> manually? using sed too? At first, I was using grep because it will jump to the line that contain <td> only and put it in the output file. (so, the <head> wont be written to the output file.

Comment: @user1988385 Ah much clearer what you meant now, see new edit, consider accepting this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: thx. that's exactly what I want :) what is this ;p} ? and, do you think I can put \n in the search pattern in the sed command? because \n isn't working. I try to find the regex for newline character but \n is the only one that come out. thx

Comment: `-n` turns off `sed` defaulting printing, and `p` is the print command so only lines that contain `<td>` are now printed, you can doing multiline matching in `sed` see [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51).

Answer (score 5):

In sed command **Use the -i option in order to change file itself**, if not, the output printed on the screen but the file stays the same.

The formula would be:

```
sed -i <targetFile> 's/<beforeText>/<afterText>/g' <targetFile>
```

For example:

```
sed -i myCredentials.txt 's/secretPassword/xxx/g' myCredentials.txt
```

**Another option** - output to another file and rename it:

```
sed 's/secretPassword/xxx/g' myCredentials.txt > temp.txt
rm myCredentials.txt && mv temp.txt myCredentials.txt
```

for more info, look at the documentation:

> **The sed utility reads the specified files, or the standard input if no
>        files are specified, modifying the input as specified by a list of com-
>        mands**.  The input is then written to the standard output.
>   A single command may be specified as the first argument to sed.  Multiple
>        commands may be specified by using the -e or -f options.  All commands
>        are applied to the input in the order they are specified regardless of
>        their origin.
>
> **-i** **Edit files in-place**, saving backups with the specified extension.
>                If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
>                is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
>                editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
>                ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `sed` to edit an existing file in place, you should give `-i` option to it.

UPD: and it's not clear what you want to do with the result of `tr` (now it goes to the script's standard output, is it intended?)

Comment: so do you mean I should do something like this: tr -d [:blank:] < $1 > $2 -----> to remove all blank in $1 and put the result in $2? Also, sed -i '....'

Comment: yes, but look at the answer from @sudo_O for radically improved solution (with everything done in sed). Btw, `\/\?` stands for "optional slash", that is, either `/` or nothing, to match both `<td>` and `</td>` at once.

Answer (score 0):

grep solution:

```
kent$  echo "<td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
    <td>hello</td>
<td>abc</td>
 <td>abc</td>"|grep -v 'abc'|grep -oP '(?<=<td>).*(?=</td>)'                                                                                                                
hello
hello
hello
```

awk solution:

```
kent$  echo "<td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
    <td>hello</td>
<td>abc</td>
 <td>abc</td>"|awk -F"</?td>" '!/abc/{print $2}'
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is 1 simple sed or awk substitution line:

```
sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]|<\/?td>|abc//g' file
awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]|<\/?td>|abc/,"")}1' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
<td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
    <td>hello</td>
<td>abc</td>
 <td>abc</td>

$ sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]|<\/?td>|abc//g' file
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want sed to modify a file you need to pass -e

Comment: Which command do you pass the `-e` to in order to edit in place?  (The answer is 'none of those mentioned in the question', sadly!)  The `grep` command takes `-e`, but it specifies the regex to be searched for.  The `sed` command takes `-e` but it specifies (a fragment of) the script.